# Unable to uninstall a font in Windows 10 - SOLVED (ish)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, fonts

UPDATE: When I went back to get screenshots, **without me doing anything**, the font, along with two others I was trying to track origins for, had disappeared.

I do not know for sure, but right now I'm thinking the fonts are related to some specific program running on my computer, and the fonts are only showing as installed when the service associated with the program is active. I'll keep an eye on this and update what I find.

==== Update No. 2 ====

I still haven't found which program is doing the weirdness, but I did find another few questions on related stackexchange sites that support the hypothesis of another program being the source of my "ghost fonts". The most relevant of such was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986744/how-to-install-a-font-programmatically-c and notes that depending how a font is programmatically installed, it may only show up as installed for a session.

==== Update No. 3 ====

The program is my Avast installation. At least, when I remembered that you could, in prior Windows versions, install fonts without copying them to the Windows/Font directory, and ran a search through my Programs Folder for "*.ttf" files, that's where the fonts *I* didn't install were located.

So, essentially, I have to find a different anti-virus software or deal with the session-only fonts ghosting in and out of my fonts list.

==== ORIGINAL QUESTION ====

I discovered a font called Dustismo Roman on my computer and I have no idea how it got on my computer. I've tried to uninstall it, but no success. Steps I have tried are below, and I'm stumped now.

1. Settings > Fonts. Opening the font page, I get the license information, but there's no file path or uninstall button listed, which are both present on some of the Windows packaged fonts like Consolas or the fonts I've picked up from Google Fonts.
2. Fonts Directory. Opening up C:\Windows\Fonts\ the font file is not present. I've double checked that I have the option to view all files, especially hidden files. It's not there.
3. Registry. I've opened the Registry Editor, navigated to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts and, again, this font is not present in the listings.

What else can I do to get rid of this font?

Some things I have confirmed: it is a selectable font in my word processor apps, and it has a decent glyph support.

Comment: Did you google this at all?  There are so many sites explaining how to.  [Try this](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/127007-delete-uninstall-fonts-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: I did, in fact, start with google. I even went through the same page you linked. It did not work. That's why I'm asking here.